# Playwright - how to hover over an element for 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, hover, playwright

I was wondering if anyone could help me out.
I'm using hover in playwright  but I need to hover over the specified element and wait for 4 seconds

I looked through the docs https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-hover and I couldn't find anything about adding some sort of delay on hover

The reason why I want to do this is because at a 4 second hover we show a tooltip with some additional information that pops up

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue of the tooltip by hovering at different places of the element that needed to be hovered. Anything else just does not work.
At one point you will identify the pattern for the tooltip to appear. For example which 2 positions are needed to trigger the toolbox with 1 attempt.

Consider that in your case maybe you need to adjust the position differently.
Maybe playing with X, then Y, perhaps a combination of both.
To get an idea of how many pixels are resealable - consider downloading a pixel ruler and measuring your 'box' of the element. You can invoke as well my_element.highlight() and run in a headed mode to visualize the issue.

```
    import random

    for _ in range(50):
        rand_int = random.randint(0, 30)
        print(f"Random number: {rand_int}")
        my_element.hover(position={'x':10.0, 'y':rand_int})
```

Comment: This isn't Javascript (but the question is).

Answer (score 1):

I think Hover should be enough as [@kozko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19895078/kozko) suggested

```
page.hover('YourSelectorToBeHovered')
page.waitForSelector("YourSelectorOfYourTooltipOnceIsOpen")
```

In case that is not enough for you, you could also try click with delay param:

> delay: <float> Time to wait between mousedown and mouseup in milliseconds. Defaults to 0.

```
page.click('YourSelector', delay=5000)
page.waitForSelector("YourSelectorOfYourTooltipOnceIsOpen")
```

[Click - Official playwright](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-click)

Comment: This looks like Python code, but the question is tagged JS. If JS, these would need `await`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [waitForSelector](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector) with the tooltip after the hover for it to start waiting until your tooltip appears.

It could be problematic depending on where the hover takes place because the tooltip can appear on the mouse location which could lead to it disappearing depending on the code